wireguard on pfsense - only some hosts reachable
I've installed wireguard on my android phone and pfsense on my home network.
It mostly works as expected:

I can run a terminal emulator on my phone and ping most hosts on my home network.

I run a Synology Drive app on my phone which connects to a Synology NAS on my home network.

I run a Reolink app on my phone which connects to a Reolink IP camera on my home network.


But there are some hosts on my home network (eg a reolink NVR) that I cannot ping or connect to.
I know the host is working since I can ping it when my phone is connected to my home network via WiFi.
Does anyone know why some hosts on my home network are unreachable while others are reachable?
